# Am i closing this socket correctly?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

For the most part, it works, however sometimes it doesn't, this code is ment to close the socket only `if(input.equals("Done")){` , am i closing it correctly? , it seems to me, from the code that i'm trying to close it regardless? Can anyone confirm or correct it from me?

```
Socket socket1;
int portNumber = 4445;
socket1 = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), portNumber);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket1.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket1.getOutputStream(), true);

pw.println("Hello");
pw.println("Hello");
pw.println("Hello");
pw.println("Hello");

String input = br.readLine();
while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(input.equals("Hi")){
        pw.println("Hello");
    }
    else  if(input.equals("Done")){
        break;
    }

    br.close();
    pw.close();
    socket1.close();
}
```

Comment: Your indentation looks odd, but otherwise it's ok. edit: nvm it's not ok.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: What exactly do u want to do with this code ?

Comment: Either you do a resource try with Socket, BufferedReader, and PrintWriter or you use a try/finally block to close them in the finally block. Plenty of examples on line.

Comment: put the close methods outside of while loop. Also, it should be `String input = null`, as otherwise you miss the first value.

Comment: i've been working on a project for a while, which is basically like a chat, locally automated chat, my server opens, this client connects. and talks to the server, until the server says " Done " , it closes the socket. From the way i can see the code, it seems that it's closing the socket regardless of " Done "and i want it to only close, if input.equals("Done")

Comment: @BioPipeRex Since you are breaking out the loop when you see a "Done", then they should be closed in either of the 2 methods I describe in my comment above.

Comment: BioPipeRex - you're closing your socket right after ANY message was read. Move socket.close functions inside input.equals("Done") else block, or, better, use my solution

Comment: @PiotrK Wrong. You don't want to close resources like that. That doesn't guarantee their closure. Your answer is suffice.

Comment: @Javarino,can you explain what do you by outside of it ? to me it seems like it's outside,

Comment: @BioPipeRex No, it's inside your while loop!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're disposing your object *inside* while loop, so they will be disposed no matter the second message is received (you're skipping the first with line just before while loop). If the second message by any chance will be DONE, then you're going out of loop without any socket disposial, so they're still inside your memory. And, as many pointed in comments, you may have problem, if any of your objects throws exceptions. The correct version for this app would be:

```
Socket socket1 = null;
int portNumber = 4445;
BufferedReader br = null;
PrintWriter pw = null;
try
{
    socket1 = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), portNumber);
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket1.getInputStream()));
    pw = new PrintWriter(socket1.getOutputStream(), true);

    pw.println("Hello");
    pw.println("Hello");
    pw.println("Hello");
    pw.println("Hello");

    String input = null;
    while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if(input.equals("Hi")){
            pw.println("Hello");
        }
        else  if(input.equals("Done")){
            break;
    }
}
finally
{
    if(br != null) br.close();
    if(pw != null) pw.close();
    if(socket1 != null) socket1.close();
}
```